# How to export Outlook Express group

Tags: microsoft-outlook, csv, export

I need to export an Outlook Express group, but it doesn't seem to have an option for that? Is there any workaround? I've tried using the options to export but they export the whole address book.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a draft email for that group, then close it. Open it again and the To field will be populated with the addresses separated by commas. Select them, copy them elsewhere and they will include the name and email.